# Validate date in java

Tags: java, date

I have to check the date displayed in one calendar is default same date of the next year in second calendar.
I have tried the following but date is not correctly displaying

```
String str = executeJavascript1("return document.getElementById('EndDate').value;");
logMessage(str);


Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date today = cal.getTime();
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1); // to get previous year add -1
Date nextYear = cal.getTime();

SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
String d = DATE_FORMAT.format(nextYear);
logMessage(d);
Assert.assertEquals(str,d);
```

Comment: Define "not correctly displaying"; what is the output you get, what output do you want? Also, make sure to double check the `SimpleDateFormat` javadoc to see whether the format you use is actually what you want.

Comment: if want if in one calendar the date is 10/08/2015 then i hav eto validate in second it is 10/08/2016

Comment: You should ensure that the 'str' and 'd' are formatted identically. Furthermore be careful with comparisons. Switching daylight savings time / summer time vs. winter time can cause severe trouble. You should instantiate the Calendar using a TimeZone.

Comment: I don't think you are simply asking to compare the date vals of 2 Calendar objs. and if they are different, return 'false', and if not, return 'true'.  I think instead you are asking to know if a given date of one Calendar value is, after fast-forwarding 365 days, going to be the same actual date of the second calendar, in essence checking to see if the next year is a leap year (or conversely, if the current year is a leap year and the following is not, but in any case, cal1_date + 365 days will not equal cal2_date).   Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: @rishusaxena Please work to make your Question more specific. As it is now, it will be closed as unclear. Also delete extraneous tags such as "selenium" that have nothing to do with your actual Question.

Answer (score -1):

Can you do this?

```
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int date = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
int month= cal.get(Calender.MONTH);
Calendar cal2 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
c2.set(year+1, month, date );
```

Comment: Please add some detail as to why you are recommending this code... what does it do, etc.